# Why is my service killed at the end of my docker build?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I created a Dockerfile such as:

```
FROM openjdk:8
COPY --from=python:2.7 / /

RUN mkdir /opt/archives
RUN mkdir /opt/var
COPY resources/bin/archives /opt/archives
COPY resources/data/* /var/opt/

RUN tar -xvf /opt/archives/apache-phoenix-4.13.1-HBase-1.2-bin.tar.gz -C /opt/
RUN tar -xvf /opt/archives/hbase-1.2.0-bin.tar.gz -C /opt/

COPY resources/conf/hbase-env.sh /opt/hbase-1.2.0/conf/
COPY resources/conf/hbase-site.xml /opt/hbase-1.2.0/conf/

RUN cp /opt/apache-phoenix-4.13.1-HBase-1.2-bin/phoenix-4.13.1-HBase-1.2-server.jar /opt/hbase-1.2.0/lib/

CMD ["/opt/hbase-1.2.0/bin/start-hbase.sh"]
```

And accordingly a docker-compose.yml file such as:

```
version: "3"
services:
        hbase:
                build: .
                command: tail -F /dev/null
```

My goal is to have this hbase java process up and running at the end of the docker build.

But after the build when I do a :

```
docker exec -it <container-id> bash
```

And that I list the java process with jps it's not running.

I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You need to actually start the containers using `docker compose up` https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

Comment: The command in the docker-compose file overwrites the one in the Dockerfile, so the start-hbase script isn't run. Remove the command in the docker-compose file.

Comment: @DanielScott Yes I do the docker compose up already, but even when i do so, when i connect to the container I don't my service running.

Comment: @HansKilian It doesn't change anything if I do that. I see the command executed during the docker logs. But I tried with or without.

Comment: `CMD` is an instruction to record in the image, when the container is run, to run that command; it doesn't actually run the command and the image doesn't contain a running service.  Compose `command:` overrides that command so the `tail` command runs instead of the service you want to run.

Comment: @DavidMaze But then how come the service isn't even running when I run the container ?

Comment: A container only runs one process, and you're telling it to run a meaningless `tail` command instead of the service.

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried without in the first place and it doesn't work either, the tail was a tentative to keep it up running.

Comment: That sounds like the `start-hbase.sh` script tries to start some processes in the background, then exits.  You need to change it to start a specific process in the foreground, or otherwise make the `CMD` launch one thing.  You shouldn't need to "keep a container running" normally.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes exactly that haha ! I was wrinting this as I received your notification. What can I do ?